# Error: could not find function "cpcp" - using extracat package in R

Tags: r

I've installed the extract package in R and am trying to follow the [examples](http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v053i07/v53i07.pdf) in the JSS paper.

when I try to run the example

`cpcp(Titanic, ord = c(4, 1, 2, 3))`

I get the error message Error:

> could not find function "cpcp" which is weird because this is one of
>   only two main plotting function delivered as part of the package.

Does anyone know anything about why cpcp seems to be missing from my extracat install? I have installed again just to be sure.

Comment: To be sure, did you load it: `library(extracat)`?

Comment: Oh, I've just found it in the small print of the package documentation: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/extracat/extracat.pdf

Comment: Name's been change to scpcp "A deprecated interactive version based on iplots (without
labeling) is still available as extracat:::cpcp.:

Comment: Side note: this package has been removed from CRAN and may misbehave.